# Multi Query PHP Question

Tags: php, sql, mysql, query-string

I wanted to execute multiple queries in one. Is there a way to condense a bunch of queries into one big string and then execute it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of queries are you building?

Comment: I'm not sure this would make sense. What kind of result set would you get back if your queries look up all different columns in different tables? This would make sense for DML statements, you could just concatenate the query strings and execute, but not queries. Show use the queries in question and maybe we can help rebuild it?

Comment: Anthony, let's say there was a table full of meta data like Wordpress does it, and instead of executing 8-12 lines of separate sql queries for one table, I wanted to do it in 1 shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use mysqli

It is the successor to the mysql functions and also exists in either procedural an object oriented implementation.

It can do multiple querys per one session and even return all different sets after the multi query. for more information read:

[multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

yes it's called a stored procedure - use 'em !!